# Convert text file contents to XML

Tags: php, xml

I have a text file that contains a list of manufacturers. How can I read the lines of the file via PHP and write a new XML file that contains all of characters on each line of text file (the manufacturer's name)?

**Text file:**

```
Sony
Pioneer
Boss
```

The **XML file to be written** would look like this:

```
<data>
<manufacturer>Sony</manufacturer>
<manufacturer>Pioneer</manufacturer>
<manufacturer>Boss</manufacturer>
</data>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) for opening the file, [DOMDocument](http://au.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) (or you could use [SimpleXML](http://au.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)) for building the XML structure and [`file_put_contents()`](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) for saving the resulting XML to file.

```
$manufacturers = file('manufactures.txt');

$dom = new DOMDocument;

$data = $dom->createElement('data');

$dom->appendChild($data);

foreach($manufacturers as $manufacturer) {
   $manufacturerElement = $dom->createElement('manufacturer');
   $text = $dom->createTextNode($manufacturer);
   $manufacturerElement->appendChild($text);
   $data->appendChild($manufacturerElement);
}

file_put_contents('manufactures.xml', $dom->saveXML());
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Tsqnd0).

Also, [Dan Grossman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6741251/convert-text-file-contents-to-xml/6741265#6741265) answer has the good idea of using `trim()` on the text node before inserting it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$lines = file('something.txt');

$xml = "<data>\n";
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $xml .= "<manufacturer>" . trim($line) . "</manufacturer>\n";
}
$xml .= "</data>";

file_put_contents('something.xml', $xml);
```

Comment: oh dear, please, don't treat XML as text... you'll have to manually deal with character encoding